# How to add multiple foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-modeladmin

I am beginner in Django.
I am having two models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=120,default=None)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=80,default=None)

class Leave(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='employee')
    number_of_days = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Now I have inline Leave Model with Employee in `admin.py`
so that I can add as many leaves I want in employees
But when I retrieve this model in views new `Leave`s are created, all I want is one employee should show `total = number of days`, but it creates new leaves, not able to build any logic here I am stuck, please ask if u don't understand what I am asking.

Comment: show your view code please

Comment: what is your expected output? you want leave count instead leaves? why you need more foreignkey

Comment: sorry , i should have clarified , i want all the number of days total in to each employee_id

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but my guess is you want to display the total number of absent days of an employee in the admin. You can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/) and [`Sum`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#sum) in particular and a custom method on your model:

```
# models
from django.db.models import Sum

class Employee(models.Model):
    def absent_days(self):
        return self.leaves.aggregate(s=Sum('number_of_days'))['s'] or 0
    absent_days.short_description = 'Absent days'  # used as column header/field label

class Leave(models.Model):
    # note the changed related name!
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='leaves')

# admin
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = [..., 'absent_days', ...]
    fields = [..., 'absent_days', ...]
    list_display = [..., 'absent_days', ...]
```

Comment: Was typing while you answered. Your aggregation solution exceeds my suggestion by far :)